# Kubernetes initContainers to copy file and execute as part of Lifecycle Hook PostStart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am trying to execute some scripts as part of statefulset deployment kind. This script I have added as configmap and I use this as volumeMount inside the pod definition. I use the lifecycle poststart exec command to execute this script. It fails with the permission issue.

based on certain articles, I found that we should copy this file as part of InitContainer and then use that (I am not sure why should we do and what will make a difference)
Still, I tried it and that also gives the same error.

Here is my ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-configmap-initscripts
data:
  poststart.sh: |
     #!/bin/bash
     echo "It`s done"
```

Here is my StatefulSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres-statefulset
spec:
  ....
  serviceName: postgres-service
  replicas: 1
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: "postgres-ghost"
        image: alpine
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /scripts
          name: postgres-scripts
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres
        lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/scripts/poststart.sh" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: dbport
        ....
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /scripts
          name: postgres-scripts
volumes:
  - name: postgres-scripts
    configMap:
      name: postgres-configmap-initscripts
      items:
      - key: poststart.sh
        path: poststart.sh
```

The error I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postStart` hook will be call at least once but may be call **more than once**, this is not a good place to run script.

The `poststart.sh` file that mounted as ConfigMap will not have execute mode hence the permission error.

It is better to run script in `initContainers`, here's an quick example that do a simple `chmod`; while in your case you can execute the script instead:

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: busybox
data:
  test.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "It's done"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  labels:
    run: busybox
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: scripts
    configMap:
      name: busybox
      items:
      - key: test.sh
        path: test.sh
  - name: runnable
    emptyDir: {}
  initContainers:
  - name: prepare
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    command: ["ash","-c"]
    args: ["cp /scripts/test.sh /runnable/test.sh && chmod +x /runnable/test.sh"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: scripts
      mountPath: /scripts
    - name: runnable
      mountPath: /runnable
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    command: ["ash","-c"]
    args: ["while :; do . /runnable/test.sh; sleep 1; done"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: scripts
      mountPath: /scripts
    - name: runnable
      mountPath: /runnable
EOF
```